# Java - Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImmutableList<Object> to ImmutableList<String>

Tags: java

I'm having this error:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImmutableList<Object> to ImmutableList<String>`

This is the code in error:
In the line `COMPLETIONS = ImmutableList.of((Object)"all");`

```
public class FactionWithdrawArgument extends CommandArgument
{
    private static final ImmutableList<String> COMPLETIONS;
    private final HCF plugin;

    public FactionWithdrawArgument(final HCF plugin) {
        super("withdraw", "Withdraws money from the faction balance.", new String[] { "w" });
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    public String getUsage(final String label) {
        return '/' + label + ' ' + this.getName() + " <all|amount>";
    }

    static {
        COMPLETIONS = ImmutableList.of((Object)"all");
    }
}
```

I dont know this.
This is a clase of bukkit

I need help
If this is very easy. but i dont know

Comment: Why are you trying to cast the string to an `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that. One thing you have it as final. 
And secondly
Immutable Objects
An object is considered immutable if its state cannot change after it is constructed.